# Craft 3 Custom Plugin: model validation

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, validation, yii

Struggling a bit here - have created a custom plugin where I want to validate form submission against a predefined model before saving to the database. All pretty straightforward so far …

However, if I try to use native (Yii 2) validation then a record is saved regardless of whether it is valid or not. For example, if I set the model rules as follows:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['formName'], 'required'],
            [['formName'], 'string', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 255, 'skipOnEmpty' => false]
        ];
    }
```

The record is saved, even if `$model->formName` is empty. For example, see the following Controller code:

```
public function actionUpdate()
    {
        $this->requirePostRequest();
        $request = Craft::$app->getRequest();
        $site = Craft::$app->getSites()->getCurrentSite();   

        $formName = $request->getBodyParam('formName');
        $formId = $request->getBodyParam('formId');

        // get ID (if exists)

        if ($formId) {
            $formRecord = FormRecord::find()
            ->where(['id'=>$formId])->one();
            // if count == null return false
        } else {
            $formRecord = new FormRecord;
        }

        $formRecord->formName = $formName;
        $formRecord->siteId = $site->id;
        if ($formRecord->validate()) {
        …
```

The code will always validate - even if the formName is empty.
This seems a bit crazy to me - am I misunderstanding something about Yii validation rules here?

Help/thoughts appreciated,

Cole

Answer (score 1):

Since Craft 3.4.0 you should be using `defineRules()` over `rules()` in your model classes.

> Models should override this method instead of [[rules()]] so [[EVENT_DEFINE_RULES]] handlers can modify the class-defined rules.

See https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/d2b867f601cd75a33a22a016d8ea823bdda614e4/src/base/Model.php#L127-L141

But that doesn't explain why your rules are not working. Be sure to place the `defineRules()` method on the record class.

```php
use craft\db\ActiveRecord;

class FormRecord extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function defineRules()
    {
        return [
            [['formName'], 'required'],
            [['formName'], 'string', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }
}
```

Then if `$formRecord->formName` is empty, `$formRecord->validate()` should evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner at craft cms,but  I think these would help you:-
1.install the plugin guest entries and look at their code
2.[look at this article](https://medium.com/@mccallister/handling-model-validation-in-craft-cms-template-forms-with-plugins-25a7a2afe27b)